# printf to show QString

Tags: c++, linux, qt5

I'm debugging a program using QString.
I added `printf` to show contents of QString but it only shows 1st letter.

Code is as below. `fprintf` is what I added.

```
    QString profilePath = mltPath;
    fprintf(stderr, "profilePath: %s\n", profilePath.data());
```

Output is

```
profilePath: /
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] -- the code shown really shouldn't even print the '/' character.

Comment: I haven't worked with Qt in ages, but doesn't QString use UTF-16 encoding internally? If so, that would explain just seeing a / on a little-endian system. There's probably a way to convert it to UTF-8.

Comment: And if it does and your compiler isn't warning you about that `fprintf()` call, turn up your warnings until it does (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc and clang).

Comment: Or just use normal C++ iostreams instead of C style stdio functions.

Comment: You can also use qPrintable(profilePath): [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qPrintable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qPrintable)

Answer (score 1):

`profilePath.data()` is a `QChar*` which is a 16 bit unicode character. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html

One solution to convert to a const char* is to this is to use `qPrintable(profilePath)` to convert the QString to const char*

```
QString profilePath = mltPath;
fprintf(stderr, "profilePath: %s\n", qPrintable(profilePath));
```

The documentation for `const char * qPrintable(const QString& str)` is here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qPrintable

Answer (score 1):

Just use [QString::toUtf8()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUtf8), e.g.
`fprintf(stderr, "profilePath: %s\n", profilePath.toUtf8());`

You shouldn't use `printf` as it is mostly used in C (or well should be).

Since you are working with Qt, why not use [QDebug](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html)?
Then all you have to do is call: `qDebug() << "profilePath:" << profilePath;`

If you use QDebug, you also gain the advantage of [categorized logging](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can use the `toLocal8Bit()` method to convert it to a `QByteArray` with your local encoding on your system [(documentation)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLocal8Bit).

So you would want this in your code:

```
QString profilePath = mltPath;
fprintf(stderr, "profilePath: %s\n", profilePath.toLocal8Bit().constData());
```